# I don't understand how these complex pulleys work

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, string

[image]

> The pulley system above requires a person to pull on the rope with a minimum force $F$ in order to lift the block of mass $m$. An inclined plane of angle $θ$ requires that same force to push the block up the ramp. Assuming ideal conditions in both situations, what is the value of $θ$?

I don't understand how to draw out the forces for this pulley and calculate θ.

Comment: Draw the tension in the rope at each mobile pulley.

Comment: this is used to pull heavier objects with the least force possible at that time  :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We do not post full solutions to homework questions on this website. With that said, here are a few hints.

**Hint 1.** The object is being pulled up by three ropes. Each of those ropes will apply a force I'll call $T$. In this case, the three ropes will all exert the same tension on the object. I.e. the upwards force on the block is $3T$.

> **Hint 2.** You must find the force the person exerts on the rope.

> **Hint 3.** To find the force the person exerts, note that the object is stationary; it does not move. It is *about to move*, but the net force on it is $0$. Note that you should express this force in terms of $mg$.

> **Hint 3.5.** Since the total force pulling the object up is equal to $mg$ then by hint (1), the force in each rope is $mg/3$. Now if each of those ropes is attached to 1 pulley which is attached to 2 more ropes, then use Concept (2). That will allow you to find the force the person is using to pull.

As for the inclined plane:

> **Hint 4.** On an ideal inclined plane, the magnitude of the minimal force that is required to push a block up the ramp is $mg \sin\theta$.

> **Hint 5.** Equate the force the person must exert as per hint (3) with $mg \sin\theta$ from hint (4).

**Concept 1.** As shown below, in a (idealized massless frictionless pulley), the tension force on both sides is the same.

[image]

**Concept 2.** As shown below, in if you have a force $F$ pulling down an idealized pulley, then the force in each string supporting the pulley is $\dfrac{F}{2}$.

[image]

Comment: good answer dude

Comment: Put a smaller (diameter) gear for larger mass in Concept 1!